# Гайд-парк - так же пишется и название района в Лондоне?

Tags: прописная

Если название Гайд-парк употребляется не как название королевского парка, а как название исторического региона Лондона и речь идет о домах в этом районе, то писать Гайд-парк надо так же и по-другому? Скажем, Гайд-Парк.

По-моему, есть различия в написании названий островов и стран:

Каймановы Острова, The Cayman Islands (англ.) — заморская территория Великобритании в Вест-Индии1. Каймановы острова включают 3 острова (Большой Кайман, Малый Кайман и Кайман-Брак), расположенные в западной части Карибского моря

Answer (score 2):

Любое название - имя собственное, пишется с прописной буквы. О строчной можно говорить только в том случае, если данное название выступает в качестве имени нарицательного.